# Making a different error handler for each command in cog file discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a seperate error handler for each command in my cog file. For example, i want the bot to say `Sorry, you do not have permission to do this! Required Permission: Administrator` for one command and `Sorry, you do not have permission to do this! Required Permission: Manage_Roles` for another. How can i do this in a cog file? I already have

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_command_error(self, ctx, error):
      if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, Sorry, you need to tell me what the new prefix is!")
      if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, Sorry, you do not have permission to do this! `Required Permission: Administrator`")
```

but this is for all of my commands. I know how to do this in a main.py file but I know its different  in a cog file. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the list of missing permissions from the `error.missing_perms` attribute .

```py
if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, Sorry, you do not have permission to do this! `Required Permission: {*error.missing_perms,}`")
```

Edit:
using `str.join`

```py
{", ".join(error.missing_perms)}
```

### References:

- [`MissingPermissions.missing_perms`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=missingpermissions#discord.ext.commands.MissingPermissions)

note: `MissingPermissions.missing_perms` returns a list, so we use `*list,` to format it, you could also use `str.join` if you don't want the parenthesis that comes with using `*list,`

Comment: Thanks, i got it working. But how exactly do I use `str.join` because it has added brackets to the permission part?

Comment: Edited my answer